# Receiving a "redirect_uri_mismatch" error when authorizing with OAUTH 2.0 only on mobile

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

here's a screenshot of the error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1DAp.jpg

here's a screenshot of OAuth client redirect uris and js origins

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eBvs.png

on desktop everything works fine, problem is when i  try to test it on a phone it shows me this error

request details says that i need to add https://main--rainbow-marzipan-5180d2.netlify.app/ to redirect uri , but its already there

ps: first post here be nice :D

Comment: Are you just missing the slash?

Comment: I think im blind and i have main-- in the beginning of the url. Ty tho